# Strange background image resolution for a Live Wallpaper

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

I read that the background image for a Live Wallpaper must be 2xWidth and 1xHeight; my device is a 320x480 so I save the background image as 640x480.

If I try to load a static wallpaper with 640x480, it works.
But if I try the same resolution for a live wallpaper, the background image doesn't fit the entire screen. But if I save the image as 960x720 (absolutely NOT my resolution) everything works fine.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check if you are *not* resizing the image before drawing it

Comment: Checked: i'm not resizing the image.

Comment: sorry, all i want to help you, but that's what all i have now

Comment: solved (it was a very stupid mistake...). Thanks anyway, Mosh